Can't reinstall macOS
I forgot my Mac password so I went to recovery and erased the volume, but now when I click install it asks me to login into App Store, but I don't have an Apple ID. The Mac was not logged in either and I can't create it from Android. Also the Safari in El Capitan recovery does not load the Apple ID site.
How can I override this Apple Store login in my Mac? (It is not an activation lock, because it asks for an email too).

Which Mac model do you have?

Also, can you use another computer to validate you have a good connection to Apple servers. https://appleid.apple.com

@nohillside I have MacBook mid 2009

@bmike Really dont have another device, wish i had

On another Mac, download ElCapitan installer https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662, create a bootable installer on USB stick and boot that on your 2009 MacBook. No need for Apple ID.

@Gilby I dont have access to other Mac, is there a way to override this?

DaleunSeun: Do you have access to a Windows machine? If not, then any Linux machine? Do you have a 16 GB or larger USB flash drive you can use?

Why don't you use internet recovery?

@hym3242 I think it got erased from my Mac, the combination just makes Local recovery boot not internet recovery, If I try to erase the disk completely there is no way of any recovery and just USB installation way is left. I dont know why..

There is an answer posted here at Ask Different which explains how to create a El Capitan bootable USB flash drive while booted to macOS Catalina. This answer is also repeated at Create Bootable Installer Directly from Downloaded File. This answer can be adapted to allow you to create this installer while booted to the El Capitan version of macOS Recovery. The necessary modifications of the steps are given below.

Ignore the original step 1. Instead, do the following.

Boot to macOS Recovery.


Complete step 2 as given. Afterwards, do the following.

Use the Disk Utility application to erase the volume where El Capitan was installed. Use the name Macintosh HD and the format Mac OS Extended (Journaled). When finished, quit the Disk Utility.

Open a Terminal Application window. Enter the following command.
diskutil unmount Macintosh\ HD

The output should appear as shown below.
Volume Macintosh HD on disk0s2 unmounted

If your identifier is not disk0s2, then make the appropriate substitution when entering the next command. The command below mounts the Macintosh HD volume as temporary file storage.
diskutil mount -mountpoint /tmp disk0s2


Open the Safari application by entering the following command.
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari &>/dev/null &

If you get the following popup, select the "Cancel" button.

Under Safari preferences, change the "File Download Location" to the device "Macintosh HD".

Download El Capitan. You can go to the URL given below, then click on the links to download the InstallMacOSX.dmg file.
http://maclinks.publicvm.com

Or, you can enter Apple's URL given below.
http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg




Since there is no Finder application, use the command below instead.
hdiutil attach /tmp/InstallMacOSX.dmg


Complete step 4 as given, except omit the sudo before the asr command. Note that the steps can be viewed from the Safari application included with the El Capitan version of macOS Recovery by entering the URL given below.
http://maclinks.publicvm.com/bootableelcapitan.html


Complete step 5 as given, except omit the sudo before the bless command.

Do not remove the flash drive as stated in the original step 6. Instead, do the following.

Shutdown the Mac.
Startup the Mac and immediately hold down the option key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear.
Boot from the flash drive.
Erase the volume where El Capitan was installed.
Install El Capitan to the erased volume.



